# Regex: "lookaround" invented for "string matching job" and "capturing" invented for "search and replace job"

Tags: regex, replace, pattern-matching

Can I say that:

> "lookaround" is invented for dealing with string "matching" job,

and

> "capturing" is invented for dealing with string "replacing" job.

Moreover

Can I conclude that:

> "capturing" is unnecessary for string "matching" job,

and

> "lookaround" is unnecessary for string "replacing" job.

If any of four quotes above is incorrect, please give me a reason or some regular expression that conflict with my four quotes above.

Comment: lookarounds are also used for replacement job and capturing groups are also used for matching job.

Comment: @AvinashRaj If you have some clear example, please post your answer below, but make sure that they are really need capturing or lookaround.

Comment: which lang you're running? Can I give you a python example?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Basically, I prefer `PCRE` but anyway, Python is OK.

Answer (score 1):

> "capturing" is unnecessary for string "matching" job?

No, it's language-dependent. In python, capturing groups are also used for matching purpose. See the below example,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'foo"bar"buzz"blah"'
>>> re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', s)
['bar', 'blah']
```

Lookarounds won't help here to extract the text present in-between double quotes. Because loorounds won't match the starting and ending quote, which results in improper results.

> "lookaround" is unnecessary for string "replacing" job.

If we want to replace `buzz` which appears as a whole word, then we may use the below lookaround based regex.

```
>>> s = "buzz bar buzz foobuzz buzz"
>>> re.sub(r'(?<!\S)buzz(?!\S)', '***', s)
'*** bar *** foobuzz ***'
```

Here we may use capturing group also, but it also possible with lookarounds.

```
>>> re.sub(r'(^|\s)buzz(\s|$)', r'\1***\2', s)
'*** bar *** foobuzz ***'
```

Comment: What you have said is about feature of programming language, not exactly feature of regex.

Comment: there isn't a regex language alone.

Comment: I see, but e.g. `findall` is just a convenience function that actually constructed from pattern matching function. You should consider function that fundamental like "search and replace" or "pattern matching".